# What dispositions can my spirits have?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-dream-drop-distance

I have one spirit that is "sidekick", one that is "driftwood", and one that is "ack-ack" (?). What are the available spirit dispositions, and what do they mean? Are there different trees of dispositions or is it all one giant continuum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every spirit has its own set of 4 dispositions, and each effects how it attacks. Generally, but not always, it falls into one of 4 categories:

- Aggressive attacking
- Defensive or mid/long-range attacking
- Magic
- Healer

With a lot of variance depending on the type of spirit. The full list of spirits and dispositions can be found [here](http://kh13.com/forum/topic/38145-list-of-dream-eaters-names-stats-recipes-more/), but there are too many to list.